# Why is this range selector not displaying the value?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Note: The following is range slider that I found online. Although, it works perfectly online - codepen, it is displaying the value dynamically when I move the slider.

**Error:**
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at javascriptFile.js:9*

Suggestion 1:

```
Move the code of rangeValue function inside if clause : if (elem)
result : the function is not even being executed though the error disappears.
```

> How ?
>
> Tried adding a console.log("hi") inside the function but that is not
>   being printed.

Reference:
[working link on codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EEaqrr)

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="value">0</div>
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0">
```

**CSS CODE**

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:700);
body {
    font-family: "Dosis", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background: #ecf0f1;
    color: #34495e;
    padding-top: 40px;
    text-shadow: white 1px 1px 1px;
}
.value {
    border-bottom: 4px dashed #bdc3c7;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10em;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin: 40px auto;
    letter-spacing: -0.07em;
    text-shadow: white 2px 2px 2px;
}
input[type="range"] {
    display: block;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: #bdc3c7;
    width: 300px;
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    outline: 0;
}
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: #e74c3c;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid white;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
​ input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid #e74c3c;
}
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:active {
    transform: scale(1.6);
}
```

**JS code**

```
var elem = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]');

var rangeValue = function(){
  var newValue = elem.value;
  var target = document.querySelector('.value');
  target.innerHTML = newValue;
}

elem.addEventListener("input", rangeValue);
```

Comment: Your `elem` variable is `null` when the code executes, which means the element you're selecting doesn't exist. It could be that it hasn't been loaded yet. Try wrapping that code in `document.body.onload = function() { /* code here */ };`

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: oops. I had to wrap the entire code in window.onload = function (){code}.

Is the a better way of doing this ?

Comment: Putting the `<script>` tag at the bottom of the HTML file is another option.